# AWS Amplify Angular Customize Authentication Component

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

I am using Amplify for Authentication with my Angular application. The authentication component is:

`<amplify-authenticator [signUpConfig]="signUpConfig"></amplify-authenticator>`

This shows the AWS Authenticator UI on my page. I have customized the look by editing/adding some css. What I am trying to do now is to somehow show a loader and disable the "Submit"/"Sign Up" button once they are clicked.

I have tried using Interceptors but they don't seem to work with AWS Auth clicks/calls.

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Well I made a qick read for the AWS API froa angular but didnt mentiong soemthing like you want.

You can try by Using Authentication Components Without the Authenticator 
"The child components displayed within the Authenticator can be used as standalone components. This could be useful in situations where, for example, you want to display your own components for specific pieces of the registration and authentication flow"

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/angular

Comment: Even if you use child components you can not get the fine grained control (like hiding or disabling) on the links / buttons used with in the components. For that you will have to write your own implementation of the authentication components. But yes as suggested by `@Abel Valdez` these child components can be used in different manner / workflow than the AWS Authenticator  has used it.